# How limit time of execution and memory limit while execution of program

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a python script to execute a program ( C, C++,Python, Java,C#,...).

I want to make sure the execution is performed within a fixed time limit and using a limited amount of memory.

How can I do this in Python or bash?

Currently the Python I am using is this:

```
os.system("time ./"+filename+"< input.txt >out.txt")
```

Comment: @sweeneyrod   i tried this  time ./prog <input.txt >out.txt

Comment: Can you edit your question to include any code you've written so far please?

Comment: @sweeneyrod         os.system("time ./"+filename+"< input.txt >out.txt")  now i want to limit time and memory

Comment: `timeout 5 command args` kills the process after 5 seconds. You can even use `timeout 0.1m` and that will kill after 6 seconds for example. So call `os.system("time timeout 5 ./"+filename+"< input.txt >out.txt")`. 

For memory limits, running `ulimit -v 100` inside a shell will limit memory for processes in that shell, but I don't know of a single process equivalent

Comment: `man bash`; look for the bits discussing `ulimit`. Alternatively, `import resource; help(resource.setrlimit)`, assuming you're on *nix and not a Windows variant.

Answer (score 0):

OK I worked out how to do it, run the following in python and you will see it work, it should fail with malloc for the second command:

```
import os
commandStr = 'timeout 4 bash -c "ulimit -v 100000000000; python -c \"[5]*10000\""'
print 'Running command with large ulimit'
os.system(commandStr)
commandStr = 'timeout 4 bash -c "ulimit -v 10; python -c \"[5]*10000\""'
print 'Running command with low ulimit'
os.system(commandStr)
```

The argument passed to `ulimit` is in kB